# Magento checkout page terms and agreements required

Tags: onepage-checkout

How can I make my terma and agremeents checkbox appear as required? All of shipping address form fields have a red color text underneath each of them. How I can I make same thing to appear beneath my terms and agreements checkbox in Checkout Page?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the "Terms and Conditions" in adminpanel it self.

And the "Terms and Conditions" will appear in last step in checkout.

Goto

> admin > system > configuration > checkout > checkout options > Enable Terms and Conditions

Comment: I have it enabled but additionaly I want it to have "This is required" kind of thing same as is with form fields when they are not validated correctly or are empty. Can I make it somehow?